# Pound sign from number format?

Tags: java

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("10");
System.out.println (String.format("Data %s", nf.format(b.doubleValue())));
```

This outputs

Data ?10

How can I get the pound sign, for US if I change locale it outputs dollar sign.

Comment: What is your target platform? Is it web or swing?

Comment: It is actually a text shown on browser so web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the encoding in which your response is rendered. Go through [this great tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your sample-code prints a £ just fine in my test. But I use urxvt-unicode - a console able to print unicode-characters. I think your console isn't able to print the unicode-char. Try another console or another medium (for example web, with correct encoding set).