# How to display "£" symbol in Eclipse console when using NumberFormat?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've made a very simple program for my class. My only issue is when I use the locale and NumberFormat Eclipse is outputting a strange symbol to the console instead of the "£" symbol.

A small example of my code is:

```
Locale english = new Locale("en", "UK");
NumberFormat GBP = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(english);
```

Then later I use:

```
System.out.println("The total tax payable for the 6 months is: " + GBP.format(totalTax));
```

The output to the console gives me:

```
 ¤1,035.19
```

I've tried each encoding option in the settings but none of them seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pound sign from number format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392824/pound-sign-from-number-format)

Comment: Not an answer, but that 'strange symbol' is the [universal currency sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GB` instead of `UK`.

```
Locale english = new Locale("en", "GB");
NumberFormat GBP = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(english);
BigDecimal totalTax = BigDecimal.valueOf(12.34);
System.out.println("The total tax payable for the 6 months is: " + GBP.format(totalTax));
```

output

```
The total tax payable for the 6 months is: £12.34
```

Comment: This worked, I feel like an idiot now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MrShiver You can also use `Locale.UK` for this.